# Having trouble intuitively understanding the definition of $R^n$ (Real coordinate space)

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook gives the following definition:

The notation $R^n$ refers to the collection of ordered lists of n real numbers, that is

$R^n = \{(x_1...x_n):x_j \in R $ for $j = 1,...,n$

What exactly does this mean? To be honest I don't even really understand what any of these symbols mean. I am having trouble trying to understand how this equation relates to what $R^n$ means on an intuitive and visual scale. Any help breaking down this equation into baby words would be greatly helpful and please add visual examples if possible (through text should be fine)

Thanks

Comment: Two-dimensional space uses two coordinates: every point in the plane can be described as a pair of numbers $(x,y)$ when you lay down a pair of perpendicular axes.  This is the setting in which you graph functions in the plane, after all.  Have you ever graphed solutions to equations like $y = 2x+5$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$ in $\mathbf R^2$?

Comment: Hello, I am aware of what $R^n$ means as a concept itself. I believe my biggest issue was translating the given equation to what I already know, because to me the equation looks like gibberish and I would like to have a breakdown of the equation itself.

Comment: The notation $\{    \}$ means the set or collection of things described inside it (you dropped the $\}$ in your post), the colon : means “such that”, and $\in$ means “element of”. So $\{(x,y) : x, y \in \mathbf R\}$ means the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. You could write ordered pairs also as $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_j$ is a real number for $j = 1$ and $2$.

Comment: It's not an equation, but a definition. Tou're missing a closing curly brace. It says that $\mathbb{R}^n$ the set of all $n$-tuples whose coordinates are real numbers -- that is, members of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I advise learning some basic set theory notation. Since it is being used for something as fundamental as $\mathbf R^n$, such notation will no doubt be used in other settings in your course or book. Ask the instructor to suggest a reference or just Google a list of set theory notation yourself.

Comment: Thank you KCd, you've been a great help.